# "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments" when trying to write stringbuilder text into a batch file

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, stringbuilder, overload-resolution

I was trying to recreate the sourcecode for a launcher to a game I made that requires making and launching a .bat file.
When it came time to wrap up the appended lines into a .bat, I found this error.
I have researched, thoroughly even. The reason I am asking myself is because none of the answers I came across matched my case. The batch sets variables, echoes some text, then will launch the game. Here's the code, thank you for helping me. I will add more information if you need it, I'll be as helpful as I can.

```
    sb.AppendLine("@echo off")
    sb.AppendLine("set ttiUsername=" + username)
    sb.AppendLine("set ttiPassword=password")
    sb.AppendLine("set TTI_GAMESERVER=10.0.0.77")
    sb.AppendLine("set TTI_PORT=7198")
    sb.AppendLine("set /P PPYTHON_PATH=<PPYTHON_PATH")
    sb.AppendLine("echo ===============================")
    sb.AppendLine("echo Welcome to Toontown Rebuilt, %ttiUsername%!")
    sb.AppendLine("echo You are connecting to server %TTI_GAMESERVER%!")
    sb.AppendLine("echo The server port is %TTI_PORT%")
    sb.AppendLine("echo ===============================")
    sb.AppendLine("%PPYTHON_PATH% -m toontown.toonbase.ToontownStart")
    Dim File As New System.IO.StreamWriter
    File.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
    Process.Start("C:\Toontown Rebuilt Source\ToontownRebuilt\Launcher.bat")
```

Comment: Where do you write your string? :-)

Comment: In the stringbuilder with appendline?

Comment: Dont ignore the help and hint that Intellisense offers as you type; viewing it in Object Browser can help too.  Especially with such a clear error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.IO.StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor requires a parameter. The name of the file or the already created Stream where the successive `Write` will dump the content of your string. You are missing that parameter.
But there are other issues that need a change here

```
Using File = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Toontown Rebuilt Source\ToontownRebuilt\Launcher.bat")
    File.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
End Using
```

The encapsulation in the Using statement ensures a proper closing and disposing of the stream

Another useful approach is [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 Dim file = "C:\Toontown Rebuilt Source\ToontownRebuilt\Launcher.bat"
 File.WriteAllText(file, sb.ToString())
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! In 4 minutes (you awnsered too quick!) I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i use your code and fix your bug for launch bat.

This is my code in VB.NET:

```
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim username As String

        username = "test"

        sb.AppendLine("@echo off")
        sb.AppendLine("set ttiUsername=" + username)
        sb.AppendLine("set ttiPassword=password")
        sb.AppendLine("set TTI_GAMESERVER=10.0.0.77")
        sb.AppendLine("set TTI_PORT=7198")
        sb.AppendLine("set /P PPYTHON_PATH=<PPYTHON_PATH")
        sb.AppendLine("echo ===============================")
        sb.AppendLine("echo Welcome to Toontown Rebuilt, %ttiUsername%!")
        sb.AppendLine("echo You are connecting to server %TTI_GAMESERVER%!")
        sb.AppendLine("echo The server port is %TTI_PORT%")
        sb.AppendLine("echo ===============================")
        sb.AppendLine("%PPYTHON_PATH% -m toontown.toonbase.ToontownStart")
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\tmp\Launcher.bat", True)
        file.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
        file.Close()
        Process.Start("C:\tmp\Launcher.bat")
```